# mysql delete text starting and ending with specific words

Tags: sql, wordpress

I have a WordPress site and i want to remove text from wp_posts table precisely in post_content field.
Example of the text i want to remove :

```
<a href="http://www.mediafire.com"><img class="aligncenter wp-image-41174 size-full" src="https://www.ritavpn.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/Best-APK-Download-Sites-for-2020.png" alt="" width="214" height="57" data-wp-pid="41174" /></a>
```

Note : http://www.mediafire.com and https://www.ritavpn.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/Best-APK-Download-Sites-for-2020.png

are dynamic they are not the some links in all the posts !

So what I'm looking for is a query to remove the text that starts with

```
<a href=
```

and ends with

```
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Run this query in mysql.

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET meta_value = replace(meta_value,'string or link','');
```

Comment: This is not what I'm looking for pleas read the topic again !